# Showing the length of a sequence is a primitive recursive function of its Gödel numbering

Tags: recursion, computability

The question verbatim is as follows:

Show that the length of a sequence is a primitive recursive function of its code if we code sequences $\langle n_0, ..., n_{k - 1} \rangle$ of positive numbers as $p_0^{n_0} \cdot ... \cdot p_{k - 1}^{n_{k - 1} + 1}$ (I assume the $n_{k - 1} + 1$ should be $n_{k - 1}$ and $p_i$ is the $i$'th prime, but this is what it says).

If I understand the question correctly, we need to define a function $f$ such that $f(p_0^{n_0} \cdot ... \cdot p_{k - 1}^{n_{k - 1} + 1}) = k - 1$ by giving $f(0)$ and $f(x + 1)$ in terms of $f(x)$ and primitive recursive functions.

The problems I have with this question is that $0$ is not the code for any sequence since the code is positive and that the prime factorizations of $x$ and $x + 1$ do not look alike at all in general.

Comment: I am not an expert, but can you make a function $g(n)=\begin{cases}1&n\text{ prime}\\0&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$ and then just say $f(n)=\sum_{i=1}^n g(i)$ (sum implemented via recursion).

Comment: @StinkingBishop If I understand the question correctly, $f(8)$ should be $1$ because it is the coding of $\langle 3 \rangle$, while your $f(8)$ is equal to $4$.

Comment: Too late to delete my comment ... so I'll try to correct it here... Really I meant you also need something like $h(i,n)=\begin{cases}1&i\mid n\\0&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$ and then $f(n)=\sum_{i=1}^n g(i)h(i,n)$ to eliminate those primes that don't divide $n$. Sorry for the mistake.

Comment: @StinkingBishop Thanks, that works! I'm just having some trouble proving it is primitive recursive. We can't say $f(n + 1) = f(n) + g(n + 1)$ because $f(n)$ is the amount of prime divisors of $n$, not $n + 1$.

Comment: Maybe with another temporary function ... $F(n,k)=\sum_{i=1}^k g(i)h(i,n)$ (partial sum up to $k$), given by recursion $F(n,k+1)=F(n,k)+g(k+1)h(k+1,n)$, and then $f(n)=F(n,n)$. Would that work?